# Unable to interact with docker service

Tags: docker, systemd, docker-compose

I'm having trouble with a docker container of mine, specifically, the `laradock/laravel-horizon` container, I'm not sure if that's relevant or not.

The issue I'm having is that I am unable to solve my problem with the container in any meaningful way, I can stop/start other containers, but specifically not this one.

`docker-composer down` successfully shuts down all containers, except for horizon.

```
$ docker-compose down
Stopping laradock_caddy_1            ... done
Stopping laradock_redis_1            ... done
Stopping laradock_mysql_1            ... done
Stopping laradock_php-fpm_1          ... done
Stopping laradock_workspace_1        ... done

; and it just hangs here indefinitely
```

Anything I try to do relating to that specific container just hangs indefinitely.

`docker ps` shows that the container is killed. Trying to start it gives me

```
$ docker-compose up -d laravel-horizon
ERROR: An HTTP request took too long to complete. Retry with --verbose to obtain debug information.
```

```
$ docker-compose --verbose up -d laravel-horizon
```

The output is below. `8bafeae5c107eef03c1887656dd9a1d188e6a6198d92da9a64ee1f1da05e9a60` is the horizon container.

```
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True, filters={u'label': [u'com.docker.compose.project=laradock', u'com.docker.compose.service=laravel-horizon', u'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/containers/json?all=1&limit=-1&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dlaradock%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.service%3Dlaravel-horizon%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D&trunc_cmd=0&size=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 1469
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 1 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- (u'8bafeae5c107eef03c1887656dd9a1d188e6a6198d92da9a64ee1f1da05e9a60')
```

At this point I don't really know what to do, a fix would be to restart docker. But the issue with this container seems to trickle upwards, as trying to restart the docker service doesn't work anymore either.

```
$ service docker restart
```

Simply hangs indefinitely

```
$ service docker stop
```

Also hangs indefinitely.

```
$ service docker start
Failed to start docker.socket: Transaction is destructive.
See system logs and 'systemctl status docker.socket' for details.


$ systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─10-machine.conf
   Active: deactivating (stop-sigterm) since Sun 2020-01-05 21:43:59 CET; 23min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 21179 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 20
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─21179 /usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --storage-driver overlay2 --tlsverify --tlscacert /etc/docker/ca.pem --tlscert /etc/docker/server.pem --tlskey /etc/docker/server-key.pem --label pro

jan 05 21:44:15 h2842287.stratoserver.net dockerd[21179]: time="2020-01-05T21:44:15.648373895+01:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0005db690, CONNECTING" module=grpc
jan 05 21:44:15 h2842287.stratoserver.net dockerd[21179]: time="2020-01-05T21:44:15.649700557+01:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0005db690, READY" module=grpc
jan 05 21:44:15 h2842287.stratoserver.net dockerd[21179]: time="2020-01-05T21:44:15.652821154+01:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
jan 05 21:44:15 h2842287.stratoserver.net dockerd[21179]: time="2020-01-05T21:44:15.652842939+01:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
jan 05 21:44:15 h2842287.stratoserver.net dockerd[21179]: time="2020-01-05T21:44:15.652865485+01:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] }" module=grpc
jan 05 21:44:15 h2842287.stratoserver.net dockerd[21179]: time="2020-01-05T21:44:15.652881868+01:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
jan 05 21:44:15 h2842287.stratoserver.net dockerd[21179]: time="2020-01-05T21:44:15.652942518+01:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0005dbb70, CONNECTING" module=grpc
jan 05 21:44:15 h2842287.stratoserver.net dockerd[21179]: time="2020-01-05T21:44:15.653145900+01:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc0005dbb70, READY" module=grpc
jan 05 21:44:27 h2842287.stratoserver.net dockerd[21179]: time="2020-01-05T21:44:27.462931856+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
jan 05 21:45:38 h2842287.stratoserver.net dockerd[21179]: time="2020-01-05T21:45:38.332807260+01:00" level=info msg="Processing signal 'terminated'"
```

I'm at a loss here, I can "fix" the issue by rebooting the server, but the issue simply returns.

It looks like docker itself is having trouble, and I have no clue where to begin to look for a solution.